# Batch download pages from a wiki without special pages

Tags: download, wget, web, wiki, batch

From time to time I find some documentation on the web that I need for offline use on my notebook. Usually I fire up wget and get the whole site.

Many projects however are now switching to wikis, and that means I download every single version and every "edit me" link, too.

Is there any tool or any configuration in wget, so that I, for example, download *only* files without a query string or matching a certain regexp?

Cheers,

*By the way:* wget has the very useful -k switch, that converts any in-site links to their local counterparts. That would be another requirement. Example: Fetching http://example.com pages. Then all links to "/..." or "http://example.com/..." have to be converted to match the downloaded counterpart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the wget man page:

> -R rejlist --reject rejlist
>
> Specify comma-separated lists of file name suffixes or patterns to
>   accept or reject. Note that if any of
>   the wildcard characters, *, ?, [ or
>          ], appear in an element of acclist or rejlist, it will be treated
>   as a pattern, rather than a suffix.

This seems like exactly what you need.

Note: to reduce the load on the wiki server, you might want to look at the -w and --random-wait flags.

Comment: Cool, I just didn't see this option. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Most of them frown on that and Wikipedia actively shuts them down with robots.txt.  I would stick to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Export

Comment: I know, that it is quite stressful for the server, but that is one of the reasons I want to download only necessary files. Anyway, some projects just don't deliver their pages in another format than wiki pages.